# Can't use ODBC connection to Access from .Net Core 3.0

Tags: ms-access, .net-core, odbc

I'm trying to connect to an Access .accdb file and read data from my c# project in VS 2019 (.Net Core 3.0). I'm on a 64-bit system, and I believe I have both 32- and 64-bit odbc drivers for Access installed.

I was able to setup a Data connection in server explorer which uses a data source name of "MS Access Database". When I test the connection, it works fine. Also, I can expand the new connection in server explorer, and I can see all of the tables just fine. I right-click the data connection and choose Modify, I can see the data source name is `MS Access Database`, and if I select "use connection string", the full connection string is

`Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=C:\Brandeis\BNCConejo_Data.accdb;defaultdir=C:\Brandeis;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin`.

As mentioned, when I use either the dsn or the full connection string in the modify connection dialog, clicking the "Test Connection" button gives me a success message. If I use either the DSN or full connection string in my code, I get this error:

`ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application`

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
   try
   {
      conn.Open();
   }
   catch (OdbcException ex)
   {
       LastError = "ODBC Error: " + ex.Message;
       return null;
   }
}
```

I've tried targeting Any CPU, x64 and x86, but none of them work. They all return the above exception message.

Any idea why the server explorer data connection works, but not the c# code, using the same connection string?

By the way, something went wrong earlier and I seemed to be missing my odbc drivers. I downloaded and ran AccessDatabaseEngine.exe and AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe, both with /quiet option so they would properly install. This left me with the odbc drivers available, but still I get the above exception.

UPDATE: The same error occurs when trying to open connection to a MySQL database using a known good DSN entry for MySQL. This DSN is working when using it from a production Access application.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this issue by completely uninstalling my 32-bit Office and installing 64-bit office.